# Resolve hostname with port using /etc/hosts

Tags: linux

I am trying to resolve example.com to localhost:4080 .

i updated /etc/hosts with

> 127.0.0.1 example.com

Now,

> ping example.com

works but

> ping example.com:4080

doesn't work .

Whats the correct way ?

Update : 
I am running on red-hat linux..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't ping ports, since ping uses ICMP.

You could use

```
nmap -p 80 example.com
```

or even hping3.